# Change h1 text with hasclass()

Tags: jquery

I got help with this script that adds the `.hover` class to 5 other classes on a timer.
Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G5LbA/13/)

I eventually want to create a class with text that correlates with each active button. At the moment I'm trying to just change the text for `h1` when `.button5` and `.hover` exist together but it's not working..

The original script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
var divs = $('#buttonblock').children('div'),
        number = divs.length,
        currentIndex = 0,
        timer;

    function setTimer() {
        divs.removeClass('hover');
        divs.eq(currentIndex).addClass('hover');
        currentIndex++;
        if (currentIndex == number) {
            currentIndex = 0;
        }

        timer = setTimeout(setTimer, 2000);
    }

    setTimer();


    divs.mouseenter(function () {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        divs.removeClass('hover');
        var div = $(this);
        div.addClass('hover');
        currentIndex = divs.index(div);
    }).mouseleave(function () {
        setTimer();
    });

});
</script>
```

My attempt:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
 if ( $(".button5").hasClass("hover") ) {
  $('h1').text('button five is active');
 }
 });
</script>
```

Comment: So you're adding the class in two seconds, but you're checking to see if it's there right now, and you're suprised that it's not there ?

Comment: Probably this is what you wanted: http://jsfiddle.net/G5LbA/17/

Comment: yes @hjpotter92 thanks! you can add it as an answer if you'd like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this functionality right there in the setTimer function like:

```
function setTimer() {
        divs.removeClass('hover');
        divs.eq(currentIndex).addClass('hover');

         $("h1").text((currentIndex + 1) + " is active");

        currentIndex++;
        if (currentIndex == number) {
            currentIndex = 0;
        }

        timer = setTimeout(setTimer, 2000);
}
```

Here is a fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/8bvhw/